# Saving and Loading Object[] information in Android APK 2.2 and up

Tags: java, android, object, load, save

So after extensive research on the subject, I've come up with the following bit of code:

```
private void loadInformation() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("save");
    ObjectInputStream in= new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    loadedInformation=(Object[]) in.readObject(); //loadedInformation is a Object[]
    in.close();
    fis.close();
}


private void saveInformation() throws IOException{
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("save", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    out.writeObject(getAllInformation()); //getAllInformation() returns Object[]
    out.close();
    fos.close();

}
```

All of which seems to work just fine, only problem is later on conditionals will begin passing when they shouldn't be and after a few saves and loads it will just crash. It seems ok but I must be doing something silly if (variable equaling one != variable equaling one) comes out true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your array really contain only objects or are they actually a user-defined type? If so, consider the fact that you must design your class in a careful manner for serialization to work. If you haven't done so already, I highly recommend reading "Chapter 11: Serialization" from [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/).

Comment: So what you're saying is... use sqlite?